# Concurrency in the Linux network drivers: probe() VS ndo_open(), ndo_start_xmit() VS NAPI poll()

Tags: networking, concurrency, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Could anyone explain if additional synchronization, e.g., locking, is needed in the following two situations in a Linux network driver? I am interested in the kernel 2.6.32 and newer.

### 1. .probe VS .ndo_open

In a driver for a PCI network card, the `net_device` instance is usually registered in `.probe()` callback. Suppose a driver specifies `.ndo_open` callback in the `net_device_ops`, performs other necessary operations and then calls `register_netdev()`.

Is it possible for that `.ndo_open` callback to be called by the kernel after `register_netdev()` but before the end of `.probe` callback? I suppose it is, but may be, there is a stronger guarantee, something that ensures that the device can be opened no earlier than `.probe` ends?

In other words, if `.probe` callback accesses, say, the private part of the net_device struct after `register_netdev()` and `ndo_open` callback accesses that part too, do I need to use locks or other means to synchronize these accesses?

### 2. .ndo_start_xmit VS NAPI poll

Is there any guarantee that, for a given network device, `.ndo_start_xmit` callback and NAPI `poll` callback provided by a driver never execute concurrently?

I know that `.ndo_start_xmit` is executed with BH disabled at least and `poll` runs in the softirq, and hence, BH context. But this serializes execution of these callbacks on the local CPU only. Is it possible for `.ndo_start_xmit` and `poll` for the same network device to execute simultaneously on different CPUs?

As above, if these callbacks access the same data, is it needed to protect the data with a lock or something?

References to the kernel code and/or the docs are appreciated.

**EDIT:**

To check the first situation, I conducted an experiment and added a 1-minute delay right before the end of the call to `register_netdev()` in e1000 driver (kernel: 3.11-rc1). I also added debug prints there in `.probe` and `.ndo_open` callbacks. Then I loaded e1000.ko, and tried to access the network device it services before the delay ended (in fact, NetworkManager did that before me), then checked the system log.

**Result:** yes, it is possible for `.ndo_open` to be called even before the end of `.probe` although the "race window" is usually rather small.

The second situation (`.ndo_start_xmit` VS NAPI `poll`) is still unclear to me and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrt the ".ndo_start_xmit VS NAPI poll" qs, well here's how am thinking:
the start-xmit method of a network driver is invoked in NET_TX_SOFTIRQ context - it *is* in a softirq ctx itself. So is the NAPI receive poll method, but of course in the NET_RX_SOFTIRQ context.

Now the two softirq's will lock each other out - not race - on any local core. But by design intent, softirq's can certainly run in parallel on SMP; thus, who is to say that these two methods, the ".ndo_start_xmit VS NAPI poll", running in two separate softirq context's, will not ever race?
IOW, I guess it could happen. Be safe, use spinlocks to protect global data.

Also, with modern TCP offload techniques becoming more prevalent, GSO is/could also be invoked at any point.
HTH!

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info. I am testing my [data race detector](http://code.google.com/p/kernel-strider/) for the kernel modules, my primary targets are network drivers. The detector reported a number of possible races in e1000 and I am now analyzing them, filtering out false positives. Among the reported races were some between poll() and ndo_start_xmit() so I wondered if my tools missed some synchronization rule obvious for the experts, hence this question.

Comment: Well, I finally managed to check if `.ndo_start_xmit` and NAPI can race against each other. You are right: not only they **can** race if not synchronized explicitly, they **do** race. I observed such race in e1000 driver by introducing delays and setting hardware breakpoints to track data accesses. I used [a modified variant](https://github.com/euspectre/racehound/tree/hwbp_new) of [RaceHound tool](https://github.com/winnukem/racehound) to do this.